# POST connect ECONNREFUSED on Bot Framework Channel Emulator

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I am encountering a weird errror on Bot Framework. It always says:

```
POST connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3978
```

This is the details on the Bot Framework Channel Operator:

```
{
"type": "conversationUpdate",
"membersAdded": [
{
  "id": "default-bot",
  "name": "Bot"
}
],
"id": "1dhnjafnclhfeml51c",
"channelId": "emulator",
"timestamp": "2017-04-22T03:56:06.215Z",
"localTimestamp": "2017-04-22T11:56:06+08:00",
"recipient": {
"id": "default-bot",
"name": "Bot"
},
"conversation": {
"id": "a1376jghbggg6a5hjc"
},
"from": {
"id": "default-user",
"name": "User"
},
"serviceUrl": "http://localhost:51293"
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017 using Bot Application Template and connecting the API through Bot Framework Channel Emulator. I've tried refreshing the Emulator to start a new message, tried restarting the website project, rebuild it, but its still the same. I didn't change the code on Bot Application template. The localhost URL is correct. I am not sure why I am encountering the error or did I missed something.

Comment: What version of BotBuilder are you using? Do you know which port is your localhost bot listening on? What are you specifying for your bot endpoint in the emulator? Is it something like http://localhost:3978/api/messages?

Answer (score 5):

Use `http://` not `https://`, if you run on `localhost` and check the right port. It is `3979` in my version, while the emulator uses `3978` on default.

Comment: got me on the default port issue in the bot emulator.   it was 3979.  never would have seen it.  thanks...